# Traveling to USA after visiting Iran

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, iran

I will be traveling to the USA and I have been issued a visa. I also have a visa issued by Iran which I visited three years ago on a pilgrimage with my son-in-law. Will there be any problems entering the USA because my passport has an Iran visa?

Comment: You may be asked some questions about the trip however there's no law preventing you from entering the USA.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: Note that under a policy change in early 2016, foreign nationals who would normally be eligible for the Visa Waiver Program but who have visited certain countries (including Iran) must instead apply for a visa. ([Details here,](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/visa-waiver-program/visa-waiver-program-improvement-and-terrorist-travel-prevention-act-faq) in the section discussing the "new eligibility requirements".)  However, if you have already applied and received a visa, and you disclosed this trip in your application, then I don't think this will be an issue *per se*.

Answer (score 2):

As part of your US visa application, you disclosed your travel history, including the trip to Iran. Unless you have been issued a new passport in the interim, you provided your passport for US visa issuance, in which your earlier Iranian visa appears. The pilgrimage visit should not present a problem when you arrive in the US and interact with border officials.